# creating https listener for ALB for a application which is running on apache2 with in Ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2, aws-application-load-balancer

I remember doing it before but now it seems I have forgotten the process.

I want to create an HTTPS listener for an ALB. However, I don't have anything in my ec2 running on 443.
Should I configure a reverse proxy which points 443 to the app running port or add my HTTPS listener with port 80 HTTP target group?

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a single Target Group pointing to your EC2 instance on port `80`.

Then you can create a port `443` listener on the ALB that uses that target group. You will have to attach an SSL certificate to the listener when you create it. The ALB will terminate the SSL connection and send the request to the backend server over port `80`.